# I need to rotate $9x^2-2\sqrt{3}xy+7y^2=10$ such that it becomes into $3x^2+5y^2=5$

Tags: coordinate-systems, transformation, rotations

I need to rotate $9x^2-2\sqrt{3}xy+7y^2=10$
such that it becomes into $3x^2+5y^2=5$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: you have a symmetric matrix of coefficients $H,$ that being half the Hessian matrix of second partials. You then find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of unit length, put those as the columns of $P,$ so that $PP^T = P^T P = I.$ Then $P^T HP=D$ is diagonal. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=X \cos \theta + Y \sin \theta$ and $y= -X \sin \theta  + Y \cos \theta $ in your quadratic. Then set the coefficient of $X Y$ to zero to get the angle of rotation $\theta$.
Your quadratic would become $aX^2+bY^2=1.$ This proceedure is called orthogonalization.